# Auto-boot to CLI in Ubuntu Server and auto login to GUI

Tags: boot, gui

I know that this question is likely to have been asked elsewhere, but despite a concerted effort I have found everything BUT what I am looking for. What I want to do is pretty straightforward. I have a server running on 14.04 server LTS. Some software that I want to run on in it necessitates a GUI, but other benefits from the CLI. What I want to be able to do is administer it remotely, and for it to boot into CLI but with one command switch to a GUI. From there I would be able to return to the CLI when I had finished. So:

1. Boot to CLI
2. Switch to GUI at will
3. Switch back to CLI, also at will...

...so that I could view what was going on from a remote desktop while my server was running a GUI.

Any help would not only be much appreciated, but the giver would be held in the highest regard :o)

David C

Comment: Too much hassle ;-) Have a look at `screen`. We use that from `/etc/crontab` to automate a session. And we use the command line to take over that screen. Interested?